# DPI awareness for WPF Windows when called from a non-WPF Application thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dpi

My WPF windows are intended to be called from an Excel Add-in and all windows and controls are defined in a DLL.

a) When I start a separate WPF application and show a Window from the dll, the application will (apparently) trigger DPI changed events which are/can be handled in the window. All is fine.

b) However when I call the Window from Excel I have problems as the window does not receive DPI changed events.

The Excel process is not DPI aware, but its Windows can be. (Office 365, when display settings are specified)

When my Add-in connects to Excel I set the DPIAwarenessContext of the main thread to MonitorV2 (which is the same as the DPIAwarenessContext of the active Excel window).

I then instantiate a WPF Application object, ofcourse without running it, but I need wpf application wide resources.

I then show my MainWindow... but I receive no DPIChanged events when I move the window between monitors.

Any shortcuts? Or do I 'just' have to listen to the windows messages and react to WinPosChanging and DPIchanged events? Which I suppose is what the wpf.Application does when it's running.

Thanks!

I've read a lot.. but I just cannot find the setting or switch needed to make wpf do it by itself.